# Advanced Pandas chaining: chain index.droplevel after groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to find the top2 values in column2 grouped by column1.

Here is the dataframe:

```
# groupby id and take only top 2 values.
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2], 
                    'value':[20,20,20,30,30,30,30,40, 40,10, 10, 40,40,40]})
```

I have done without using chained grouping:

```
x = df.groupby('id')['value'].value_counts().groupby(level=0).nlargest(2).to_frame()
x.columns = ['count']
x.index = x.index.droplevel(0)
x = x.reset_index()
x
```

Result:

```
   id  value  count
0   1     30      4
1   1     20      3
2   2     40      3
3   2     10      2
```

Can we do this is ONE-SINGLE chained operation?

So, far I have done this:

```
(df.groupby('id')['value']
 .value_counts()
 .groupby(level=0)
 .nlargest(2)
 .to_frame()
.rename({'value':'count'}))
```

Now, I stuck at how to drop the index level.
How to do all these operations in one single chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `apply` and `head` without the second `groupby`:

```
df.groupby('id')['value']\
  .apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().head(2))\
  .reset_index(name='count')\
  .rename(columns={'level_1':'value'})
```

Output:

```
   id  value  count
0   1     30      4
1   1     20      3
2   2     40      3
3   2     10      2
```

Timings:

```
#This method
```

> 7 ms ± 116 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

```
#Groupby and groupby(level=0) with nlargest
```

> 12.9 ms ± 136 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Comment: Thanks, I am always scared to use the `apply`  function as it is said to be slow and be avoided as much as possible and tend to use `groupby`, but in this case `apply` seems to be the winner.

Comment: @astro123 Yes, you are correct.  I would reframe from using applys also.   However, in this case versus two groupbys, apply appears to be more performant.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below:

```
(df.groupby('id')['value']
.value_counts()
 .groupby(level=0)
 .nlargest(2)
 .to_frame()).rename(columns={'value':'count'}).reset_index([1,2]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution:

```
df.groupby('id')['value'].value_counts().rename('count')\
    .groupby(level=0).nlargest(2).reset_index(level=[1, 2])\
    .reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using solution from @Scott Boston, I did some testing and also 
tried to avoid apply altogether, but still apply is as good performant
as using numpy:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

np.random.seed(100)
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':np.random.randint(0,5,10000000), 
                    'value':np.random.randint(0,5,10000000)})

# df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2], 
#                     'value':[20,20,20,30,30,30,30,40, 40,10, 10, 40,40,40]})


print(df.shape)
df.head()
```

## Using apply

```
%time
df.groupby('id')['value']\
  .apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().head(2))\
  .reset_index(name='count')\
  .rename(columns={'level_1':'value'})

# CPU times: user 3 µs, sys: 0 ns, total: 3 µs
# Wall time: 6.2 µs
```

## Without using apply at al

```
%time
grouped = df.groupby('id')['value']

res = np.zeros([2,3],dtype=int)
for name, group in grouped:
  data = np.array(Counter(group.values).most_common(2))


  ids = np.ones([2,1],dtype=int) * name
  data = np.append(ids,data,axis=1)
  res = np.append(res,data,axis=0)

pd.DataFrame(res[2:], columns=['id','value','count'])
# CPU times: user 3 µs, sys: 0 ns, total: 3 µs
# Wall time: 5.96 µs
```